How do I request exact amounts without excess in a logistics chest?
I'm trying to build a set of circuits that will fill a train car with a specific number of items. The idea is to fill the train with all the buildings and stuff you need to build a new base further away.
The items are requested by a blue requester chest, the requests themselves are set by the circuit connection. The whole setup looks like this:

In the displayed arithmetic combinator I substract the items in the train and in the hand of the inserter from the list of desired items I set in a constant combinator. That difference is the input for the circuit connection of the requester chest.

The requester chest is set to request items based on the circuit connection. It is also set to trash all unrequested items.

The inserter is set to transmit the hand contents.

At first it looked like this worked, but it does actually transfer a few too many items in many cases. The -12 in the screenshot are the items that were inserted above the set number by this circuit.
Is there a design flaw in my circuit? Can this be done the way I've been trying to do this?
I first wanted to just use filters on the train cars, but could not come up with a good way to unload those with exact numbers. And it seemed like I would need a circuit network for this anyway.

I usually end up with a second inserter grabbing excess items back out of the train car.

@AdamStarrh I've done the same when loading rockets in the Space Exploration mod.  One big advantage of loading and then "trimming" this way is that you don't have to reduce the stack size to 1 for loading inserters.

As far as I know, there are no ways to get logistic bots to always deliver exact amounts. So, you can’t rely on the chest containing the correct stuff. Instead, you have to make sure the inserter only picks the right items.

Don’t read the inserter’s hand contents, just the train.
Do set the inserter’s filter using the request signal.
Use "Override stack size" to set the stack size to exactly 1.

This way, the inserter will only move items the train needs, and never more than wanted — the filter will be updated before the hand can grab another item.
This may be slow, but you can work around that by using more than one inserter for separate groups of items.
You will also need to turn off the filter (e.g. by multiplying it all by zero) whenever a train is not present; otherwise the inserter will grab a random item that it shouldn’t whenever the station is unoccupied.

The slowness can also be avoided by dynamically setting the stack sized based on a signal, which can be calculated and set to whatever amount is remaining.

@SimonForsberg there are other ways as well. You can squeeze in 24 long inserters pulling from 24 different requester chests per train car to parallelize, which is probably the most Factorio suggestion. You can also set up pairs of inserters for one item type; the first is hand size 1 as described. The second is a larger hand size with a target fill of the real target minus its hand size minus two (or so, depending on relative rotation speeds on the two inserters). That way, both inserters fill the train until it is nearly full, then the multi inserter stops and the single inserter tops it off

And since this is tagged space age, you can use quality inserters that turn faster to improve any of those approaches.
